# WCF: How do I add a ServiceThrottlingBehavior to a WCF Service?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, throttling

I have the below code for returning back an instance of my WCF Service `ServiceClient`:

```
    var readerQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()
    {
        MaxDepth = 6000000,
        MaxStringContentLength = 6000000,
        MaxArrayLength = 6000000,
        MaxBytesPerRead = 6000000,
        MaxNameTableCharCount = 6000000
    };


    var throttlingBehaviour = new ServiceThrottlingBehavior(){MaxConcurrentCalls=500,MaxConcurrentInstances=500,MaxConcurrentSessions = 500}; 
    binding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.None) {MaxReceivedMessageSize = 6000000, ReaderQuotas = readerQuotas};

    dualBinding = new WSDualHttpBinding(WSDualHttpSecurityMode.None)
                      {MaxReceivedMessageSize = 6000000, ReaderQuotas = readerQuotas};

    endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:28666/DBInteractionGateway.svc"); 

    return new MusicRepo_DBAccess_ServiceClient(new InstanceContext(instanceContext), dualBinding, endpointAddress);
```

Lately I was having some trouble with timeouts and so I decided to add a throttling behavior, like such:

```
    var throttlingBehaviour = new ServiceThrottlingBehavior () {
        MaxConcurrentCalls=500, 
        MaxConcurrentInstances=500,
        MaxConcurrentSessions = 500
    };
```

My question is, **where in the above code should I add this `throttlingBehaviour` to my `MusicRepo_DBAccess_ServiceClient` instance?**

---

From some of the examples I found on the web, they are doing something like this:

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService));
ServiceThrottlingBehavior throttleBehavior = new ServiceThrottlingBehavior
{
    MaxConcurrentCalls = 40,
    MaxConcurrentInstances = 20,
    MaxConcurrentSessions = 20,
};
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(throttleBehavior);
host.Open();
```

Notice that in the above code they are using a `ServiceHost` whereas I am not, and they are then opening it (with `Open()`) whereas I open the `MusicRepo_DBAccess_ServiceClient` instance...and this is what got me confused.

Comment: Can't you have this in a configuration file?

Comment: I need to share this wcf service with multiple projects without them having an app.config file...that's why i'm building the config programmatically

Comment: Where are you hosting the service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the behavior in the configuration file afaik, and the generated client will obey, using behaviors.

Some configuration sections excluded for brevity

```
<service 
    behaviorConfiguration="throttleThis" />

        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="throttleThis">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
                <serviceThrottling
                    maxConcurrentCalls="40"
                    maxConcurrentInstances="20"
                    maxConcurrentSessions="20"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
```

Answer (score 18):

Can be done in code for those, like me, who configure at runtime.

vb version:

```
    Dim stb As New ServiceThrottlingBehavior
    stb.MaxConcurrentSessions = 100
    stb.MaxConcurrentCalls = 100
    stb.MaxConcurrentInstances = 100
    ServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(stb)
```

c# version:

```
    ServiceThrottlingBehavior stb = new ServiceThrottlingBehavior {
        MaxConcurrentSessions = 100,
        MaxConcurrentCalls = 100,
        MaxConcurrentInstances = 100
    };
    ServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(stb);
```

Answer (score 6):

Throttling is a service side (server) behavior not client side one

Arnon