# WCF connection limit mechanism

Tags: wcf

In my situation, I have a service that will be called by a thousand users in a period. but I would like to limit them to 100 user per times, and throw a fault contract if the 101th user has connected to. And the client side application retries after a while.

How can i achieve it in my service?

Answer (score 0):

You can use service throttling to limit the number of concurrent users, connections, etc., but since WCF queues the waiting connections, I don't think there's a way to pick out #101 and send him/her the bad news.

Here's a stackoverflow link talking about throttling:

[WCF: How do I add a ServiceThrottlingBehavior to a WCF Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794338/wcf-how-do-i-add-a-servicethrottlingbehavior-to-a-wcf-service/18231627#18231627)

Comment: I tried this setting in my config file. The exceed client did not receive any exception and just keep waiting until the accepted connection is disconnected from server. However, the exceed client did not complete its task.

Comment: Sorry, I have no answer for that. I've been working a WCF project for 18 months (industrial scale) and my experience using basichttpbinding is that requests will be delayed, not refused, until the request comes up in the queue. We performance tested and were able to run uploads (24k binaries) to the tune of 160 requests/second. That's 1000 multithreaded, concurrent users throwing 40 packages each, without delay, at a single WCF server - every request queued and was processed. Not one request was dropped.